# Breaking the set - meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases, neologisms

**Breaking the set**

What does this expression mean? I hear this expression often used in the context of alternative media reports and debates. Here's the [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BplWla_h1gQ), right at the beginning the host uses that phrase:

> Hi, I'm Sean Stone, today we're breaking the set on Buzzsaw

Comment: We need more context. Is there an example sentence you can give us?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the name of a television programme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  may be referring to:

[Breaking the Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_the_Set) which is a television program on RT network. It is hosted by Abby Martin from Washington, D.C.

Comment: Yes, that's where they use it.

Comment: Initially I was quite thrilled by the question, and listening to the Youtube clip I believed the expression was a verb, but user71185 is quite correct; the host is only stating that they are the name of the programme (Breaking The Set) as in "*We're The Today Show* and today we'll be talking..."

Comment: @Mari-LouA the clip is of a show called "Buzzsaw" and they were interviewing a "Breaking the Set" correspondent. I'm guessing the anchor said "Today we're breaking the set on Buzzsaw" as a pun.

Comment: @MattЭллен a pun? You could've fooled me, maybe next time the screenwriters should tell the presenter. :)

Answer (score 0):

A set is a place you have chosen to "set" a snare. Breaking a set is the removal of the snare and associated camouflage, in UK usage.

Comment: How does that meaning of *set* relate to the question?

Answer (score -1):

There are several potential meanings of the term:

- Permanently separating pieces in a "matched set", such as a set of dishes.
- "Striking" a theatrical set -- taking down backdrops, etc.
- In the case of an object that has "taken a set" such that it fits or conforms to some shape, manipulating the object to eliminate that shape.
- In the case of some semi-fluid material, such as cake icing, which will tend to "set" if left undisturbed for a time, stirring it or otherwise forcing it to become fluid again.

And probably a few others.

Answer (score -1):

[groan] As already mentioned, *"Breaking the Set"* was a television program mixing **media criticism** with investigative journalism.

The *set* in question is a **TV set** (a television receiver). And *"breaking the set"* means exactly that:

[image]

> The original opening credits depict Martin applying a sledgehammer to
>   a television tuned to CNN.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abby_Martin#Breaking_the_Set